# Discrepancy between interface tick counter and multivariate plot time-steps (x-range) when plotting in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Why is the tick tracker (as x-range) on multiple-variable plots greater than the interface tick tracker (in the top navigation pane, beneath the simulation speed adjuster slider) as plots update?

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: It doesn't, unless you've played with the `plot-pen-interval`.  (Prove this to yourself by making a trivial plot.)  Note that you can always use `plotxy`.

Comment: @ Alan There are five outputs being plotted and each one of them is on the y-axis while they all share an x-axis (which is the ticks (time-step)). I set the duration of the simulation for a 1000 but by the time 1000 ticks is reached on the interface tick tracker, the plots show 1120 as the upper limit of the x-range on the x-axis. How might using plotxy solve this?

Comment: I am going to guess that things are working fine.  That is, I guess that your lines stop at 1000, before the end of the tick range.  The xrange is automatically adjusted when lines hit the end.  This leaves some extra space so that it will not be adjusted every tick.  If you consider the extra space a real problem, you can reset the range any way you wish: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/set-plot--range.html  hth